# Run javascript without UIWebView possible?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to run some javascript code (having perhaps an `NSString` as input) without using a `UIWebView`? I would like to run this code in a separate thread so UIWebView is not possible and I don't really want to render anything, just get back the results.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried this, but here is one idea:

Write code to allocate an empty `UIWebView` but doesn't add it as a subview anywhere, and just directly call [`- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) on your javascript.

Then use `NSOperation` to run that in parallel.

Any reason that might not work for you?  I think it would avoid displaying anything for the `UIWebView`.

As a side note, I can't think of anything you can do in javascript that you can't do more quickly directly in Objective-C.  Except maybe parsing javascript that you get externally, which may be considered a no-no by Apple, depending on the details.

Guessing at your goals: If you want to parse a JSON server reply, I recommend the [json-framework library hosted on google code](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).  It has a nice interface, and it is surprisingly easy to learn and integrate.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, for every UIWebView method I try to call I get "bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xf42930: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now..."

As for my reasons, I'm mostly experimenting :)

Comment: Unless explicitly documented, it's not safe to call ANY method other than retain* on a UIKit object. So I wouldn't expect this to ever work.

Comment: *technically release is thread-safe by itself, but if you are the last person to release an object, it may cause dealloc to be run on your thread, which is not always safe.

Answer (score 1):

I think Parmanoir's article [Taming JavascriptCore within and without WebView](http://parmanoir.com/Taming_JavascriptCore_within_and_without_WebView) may give you some advice.

Comment: JavaScriptCore is not exposed in the SDK (WebKit is a private framework) but the link is very interesting, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
 self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(getResults:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)getResults
{
    NSString *value = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascript"];
}
```

Any reason you couldn't just do something like this. Shouldn't be that big of an overhead on your main thread.