# Evaluate Javascript code in swift without a webview

Tags: javascript, swift

so I am writing a radio station app that dynamically loads ads. The original solution was to go to https://cdn.azureradio.com/invocation/clearwater/iOS/the_beat.html in a WebView and then I used Swift Soup and souped the webview for the variables I needed. However, I recently found out that Web Views do not load requests in the background, IE: if the device is locked.

This obviously poses an issue. With that said, I decided on making an HTTP request. I called the url and got a Javascript string. I need to know of a way to run the javascript code and put the html that it generates into a variable so that I can soup the variable. Currently, the Javascript code that I get is

```
<!-- Azure Spot Server Javascript Tag - Generated with Revive Adserver v5.0.5 -->
<script type='text/javascript'><!--//<![CDATA[
   var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://azureradio.com/ads/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://azureradio.com/ads/www/delivery/ajs.php');
   var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
   if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
   document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
   document.write ("?zoneid=7&amp;target=_top");
   document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
   if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
   document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
   document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
   if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
   if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
   if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
   document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
//]]>--></script>
```

I have no idea how to run this code in swift to generate a URL without using `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()")` 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run javascript without UIWebView possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302276/run-javascript-without-uiwebview-possible)

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: which of 3 methods described there did you try?

Comment: I tried all of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JavaScriptCore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore), which is a way to directly access WebKit's JavaScript engine without actually using an instance of a web view.

```swift
import JavaScriptCore

let context = JSContext()!
let value = context.evaluateScript(yourJavaScriptString)
print(value)
```

The `value` that is returned is the value of the last element that was evaluated.

Comment: So I used  let context = JSContext()!
                let value = context.evaluateScript(contents)
                print(value!)
                              and the issue is it prints undefined, then says "Could not cast value of type 'JSValue' (0x1dec940c8) to 'NSString' (0x1debc2018)."

Comment: @BrianBecker Try to use value.toString() https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/jsvalue/1451409-tostring

Comment: It is still undefined.

Comment: I decided to put the sleep(4) to allow time for the Javascript to run.